# getrusage() get system time, user time. Unix programming help

Tags: c++, timer, systemtime, getrusage, rusage

I am writing a shell where I need to launch several child processes at once and record the system time and user time.

So far I am able to do it. The only problem is that I am using wait4 to grab the system resources used by the child program and put it in my rusage structure called usage.

How can I launch all the processes at the same time and keep track of the user and system times? I can remove the wait4() system call and use it outside to loop so I can make the parent wait, but if I do that then I can only record the times for the last process and not all of them.

Do you have any idea how I can fix this?

```
execute(commandPipev,"STANDARD",0);
wait4(pid,&status,0,&usage);
printf("Child process: %s\t PID:%d\n", commandPipev[0], pid);
printf("System time: %ld.%06ld sec\n",usage.ru_stime.tv_sec, usage.ru_stime.tv_usec);
printf("User time:   %ld.%06ld sec\n\n",usage.ru_utime.tv_sec, usage.ru_utime.tv_usec);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A convoluted answer.

In a POSIX environment, launch the children, then use `waitid()` with the `WNOWAIT` option to tell you that some child has exited.  The option leaves the child in a waitable state - that is, you can use another wait-family call to garner the information you need.  You can then use the non-POSIX `wait4()` system call to garner the usage information for the just exited child, and deal with the accounting you need to do.  Note that you might find a different process has terminated between the `waitid()` and `wait4()` calls; you need to use a loop and appropriate flags and tests to collect all the available corpses (dead child processes) before going back to the `waitid()` call to find out about the other previously incomplete child processes.  You also have to worry about any of the wait-family of functions returning the information for a process that was previously started in the background and has now finished.

The Linux man page for [wait4(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/wait4.2.html) suggests that `WNOWAIT` might work directly with `wait4(2)`, so you may be able to do it all more cleanly - if, indeed, you need the option at all.

Consider whether you can use process groups to group the child processes together, to make waiting for the members of the process group easier.